# Accessing the SSRS SOAP API from perl

Tags: perl, soap, reporting-services

I would like to know if its possible to access the SSRS SOAP API from Perl. I have written some C# applications that use SSRS, but most of my code base is in Perl running on Unix. I am not really familiar with SOAP at all.

I would like to know if its even possible, and if it is, I would like to know how to code up the following example int perl:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx

Thanks

EDIT:

I am only looking for an example of how to connect and execute a function. 
In essence, I am looking on how to write the following(simplified) C# code in Perl?

```
ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
rs.Url = "<server adress here>";
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
CatalogItem[] items = rs.ListChildren("/", true);
foreach (CatalogItem i in items){
    Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
}
```

Comment: Probably you want read this: http://soap-wsdl.sourceforge.net/ or http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL.pm or maybe http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/01/soap.html and http://www.soaplite.com/

Comment: also [XML::Compile::WSDL11](http://p3rl.org/XML::Compile::WSDL11)

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11466218/1331451) that was less specific. It might have a more general overview. I do recommend `SOAP::WSDL` though. It is hard to learn, but it's worth it, and the author is really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, SOAP::WSDL seems to be what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 way for it

1. SOAP::Lite https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/02_SOAP_Lite.pl
2. XMLRPC::Lite https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/03_2_XMLRPC_Lite.pl

Comment: Links are broken. Is this content still available?

Comment: thanks for advice, work link is

---
    1. https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/02_SOAP_Lite.pl
---
    2. https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/4_trans/03_2_XMLRPC_Lite.pl